# Nodejs splice JSON elements not working well

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, splice

I've got the following nodejs function that retrieves an api's data (JSON) and tries to erase all the 0 Balance elements and send the JSON to frontend.

```
app.get('/getapibittrex', function(req, res){

  var url="https://bittrex.com/api/v1/account/getbalances?apikey="+req.query.apikey;                
                  request({
                    url: url,
                    json: true
                }, function (error, response, body) {

                    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                            var datos= body.result;

                            for ( var i = 0 ; i < datos.length; i++ ) {
                                if (datos[i].Balance==0)  {
                                    datos.splice(i,1);
                                }
                            }   

                            res.send(datos);
                    } else  { 
                    console.log("Error calling API: "+error);
                    }
                });

});
```

On the other hand when i call this function i get elements with 0 balance!! What i am getting now is:

```
[
  {
    "Currency": "BTC",
    "Balance": 0.15080873,
    "Available": 0.143913061,
    "Pending": 0,
    "CryptoAddress": "1BtAz5AXbA4yvuSMneeSFnwdCGoHiSF6dA",
    "Requested": false,
    "Uuid": "4662193c-2ca1-4729-beb8-85a373a9879e"
  },
  {
    "Currency": "BOST",
    "Balance": 0,
    "Available": 0,
    "Pending": 0,
    "CryptoAddress": "BBdyTs52CmfX9MW1e8rYvoEFBvXByVYXaQ",
    "Requested": false,
    "Uuid": "4662193c-2ca1-4729-beb8-85a373a9879e"
  },
  {
    "Currency": "VOOT",
    "Balance": 0,
    "Available": 0,
    "Pending": 0,
    "CryptoAddress": "VDcdFniPZnfqT5jYVQsmqTfRXFpcGarKc5",
    "Requested": false,
    "Uuid": "4662193c-2ca1-4729-beb8-85a373a9879e"
  },
  {
    "Currency": "CLOAK",
    "Balance": 561.25771864,
    "Available": 0,
    "Pending": 0,
    "CryptoAddress": "C3SkQ7uv1kZU7ZnpdcvCT2NYpFAqrR2Qdm",
    "Requested": false,
    "Uuid": "4662193c-2ca1-4729-beb8-85a373a9879e"
  },
  {
    "Currency": "LOL",
    "Balance": 0,
    "Available": 0,
    "Pending": 0,
    "CryptoAddress": "LdTMw3czCvmmKJCSCgkC2sFsRPz91x7tPp",
    "Requested": false,
    "Uuid": "4662193c-2ca1-4729-beb8-85a373a9879e"
  },
  {
    "Currency": "HPY",
    "Balance": 0,
    "Available": 0,
    "Pending": 0,
    "CryptoAddress": "HS38GKGBKrraiNbyPHM1gmruCtA8N7B7PW",
    "Requested": false,
    "Uuid": "4662193c-2ca1-4729-beb8-85a373a9879e"
  },
  {
    "Currency": "ATH",
    "Balance": 0,
    "Available": 0,
    "Pending": 0,
    "CryptoAddress": "AY9P5Q3MhfsFG959UrEd6UV9nfVnmgjrBD",
    "Requested": false,
    "Uuid": "4662193c-2ca1-4729-beb8-85a373a9879e"
  },
  {
    "Currency": "PTC",
    "Balance": 14467.59987795,
    "Available": 0,
    "Pending": 0,
    "CryptoAddress": null,
    "Requested": false,
    "Uuid": "4662193c-2ca1-4729-beb8-85a373a9879e"
  },
  {
    "Currency": "RZR",
    "Balance": 45.18269779,
    "Available": 0,
    "Pending": 0,
    "CryptoAddress": null,
    "Requested": false,
    "Uuid": "4662193c-2ca1-4729-beb8-85a373a9879e"
  },
  {
    "Currency": "KORE",
    "Balance": 4923.65705238,
    "Available": 0,
    "Pending": 0,
    "CryptoAddress": null,
    "Requested": false,
    "Uuid": "4662193c-2ca1-4729-beb8-85a373a9879e"
  },
  {
    "Currency": "TAC",
    "Balance": 4744.48127806,
    "Available": 4744.48127806,
    "Pending": 0,
    "CryptoAddress": "TcuQAW5QqCHwtpiGDU6uaox8eG3z3zvugZ",
    "Requested": false,
    "Uuid": "4662193c-2ca1-4729-beb8-85a373a9879e"
  },
  {
    "Currency": "AERO",
    "Balance": 0,
    "Available": 0,
    "Pending": 0,
    "CryptoAddress": "APgKhLWQs1sdbgPHqs228nVdbH3B3xDBrM",
    "Requested": false,
    "Uuid": "4662193c-2ca1-4729-beb8-85a373a9879e"
  },
  {
    "Currency": "SC",
    "Balance": 1620.08759994,
    "Available": 336.88682308,
    "Pending": 0,
    "CryptoAddress": "BFUWs4gnZpB8Qb7RoiYjnst1iSqHCRC6Ec",
    "Requested": false,
    "Uuid": "4662193c-2ca1-4729-beb8-85a373a9879e"
  }
]
```

There must be something that i am missing....
Regards,

Comment: Bad idea to change the collection while iterating it. Seriously :).

Comment: Of course, what @YuryTarabanko is getting at is that you're mutating the array as you're iterating over it, so you're modifying it's length as you operate on it's parts. This is always going to produce unexpected results, as `i` is incrementing once, but it's related reference is decrementing more than once per removal, and the length is decreasing. See: http://jsfiddle.net/jaZNY/ Notice it only runs three iterations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` and do not reinvent the wheel.

```
var datos = body.result.filter(function(data){
    return !!data.Balance;
});
```